# When does iface.mapCanvas().layers() get updated to the contents of QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()?

Tags: qgis-plugins, pyqgis, layers

Since the topic might be a bit cryptic, I'll try to explain where my problem is.

I am currently developing a QGIS plugin, where I am creating and adding some layers automatically, which I would like to activate afterwards. So far, so good, not a big deal. Hence I am doing this process several times, I created a method for iterating over the layers.

And now the problem is:

I create and add the layer:

```
type = 'Polygon'
crs = '?crs=' + self.project_crs
shape_layer = QgsVectorLayer(type + crs, layer_name, 'memory')
shape_layer.setProviderEncoding('System')

# add the layer to the layer-legend
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(shape_layer)
```

But if I want to access the layer by iterating over the `iface.mapCanvas().layers()` and running:

```
for layer in self.iface.mapCanvas().layers():

    if layer.name() == layer_name:
        return layer
```

'None' is returned. Strange thing, because the problem could be avoided, by either accessing the `mapCanvas()` prior to starting iteration:

```
layers = self.iface.mapCanvas().layers()
for layer in self.iface.mapCanvas().layers():

    if layer.name() == layer_name:
        return layer
```

Or, by iterating over either `self.iface.legendInterface().layers()` or `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()`, which both are "updated" instantly.

Could anyone explain the mechanisms behind the `addMapLayer()` function and in general regarding the memory management behind QGIS? Or does anyone know where to read something about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you access the `QgsMapLayerRegistry` if you want access to the layer object again.  The layer may or may not be in the canvas i.e layers that are not visible are not in `canvas.layers()`.

`addMapLayer()` should add it to the canvas and update `layers()` automatically.  If not it might be a bug. Like I said it's safer to use the registry to find the layer if you need access to it.